# How do I access safemode in windows 10 and reset the graphics driver, in an out of sync display?

Tags: windows-10, safe-mode, display-driver

My PC(HP pro 3500MT) was updated to windows 10,
All I could see on the monitor is an out of sync error, probably due to an issue with the display driver.
I have no access to the Shift + Restart or the startup options.
So

> How do I access safemode in windows 10 and reset the graphics driver, in an out of sync display?

Thank you

Comment: Wait. It's a problem with your monitor, right? Not your HP? When do you getting this sync error?

Comment: The problem is with the display driver , Everything was perfect after I added another PCI express video card; but it doesn't solve my problem of accessing safemode after an out of sync display error.

Comment: The out of sync error is displayed just after windows 10 boot animation.

Comment: [Boot from a W10 recovery disc.](http://www.7tutorials.com/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening with me but I got into safemode.
If it goes into automatic repair go to advanced options
Then press F5 and you should go to safemode with networking you will not have sound tho. After that if your PC has a bios check if it isn't booting from a DVD or A CD. 
If this doesn't work reinstall windows.

Comment: So what if it does not go into automatic repair?

Answer (score -1):

> **Start the computer in Safe Mode** – The second way to get back your original display settings is to start up in Safe Mode, which basically loads Windows in a stripped down state. Safe Mode loads up at a lower resolution and therefore allows you to log in and change the settings back.To start up in Safe Mode, you simply press and hold the F8 key when the computer starts to boot up. This is usually when you see the manufactures logo and the BIOS being loaded. Once you press F8, you’ll be presented with a set of options as shown below: 
>   [image: safe mode]

**Source:** [Fix Blank Screen After Changing Computer Display Settings](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/what-to-do-with-a-blank-screen-after-changing-your-computers-display-settings/)

Comment: The F8 key option is not functional in windows 10.

Comment: It will do the F8 thing but only if you enable the BootMenuPolicy to Legasy using BCDEdit.. certannly the thing was not designed to do that, but windows will always have 7 ways to do anything :-)  The Shift + Restart  advanced troubleshooting method looks like the design, but i dont have 10 to test yet.